# LeafletR map not showing in browser

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio

I'm looking for guidance on getting a basic example of leafletR package to show a map in the browser.  Working with the most basic example, the map doesn't show up in the browser.  I've checked the .html and .json files, which are present and appear to properly formatted.  Javascript inspector shows this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///var/folders/_0/tdgf_k7x77qdn64_gk9ynljm0000gp/T/Rtmp6O4QZM/Fiji_Earthquakes/quakes.geojson. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm on a Mac: OSX 10.7.5
RStudio Version: 0.98.857

Code

```
library(leafletR)


data(quakes)

# store data in GeoJSON file (just a subset here)
q.dat <- toGeoJSON(data=quakes[1:99,], dest=tempdir(), name="quakes")

# make style based on quake magnitude
q.style <- styleGrad(prop="mag", breaks=seq(4, 6.5, by=0.5),     style.val=rev(heat.colors(5)), leg="Richter Magnitude", fill.alpha=0.7, rad=8)

# create map
q.map <- leaflet(data=q.dat, dest=tempdir(), title="Fiji Earthquakes", base.map="osm", style=q.style, popup="mag")

# view map in browser
browseURL(q.map)
```

Thank you in advance for any advise.

Comment: You will need to open a local webserver to view the html, since it is making requests to get the json.

Comment: I opened a local webserver and got localhost working, but still couldn't produce the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution to open the map using a local web server is to take advantage of RStudio's HTML viewer.

```
rstudio::viewer(qmap)
```

Comment: this works,  Thanks.  Although I still need to figure out how to get the map produced inside a shinyApp I'm creating.

Comment: @glynnsc Have you tired using 'getwd()' instead of 'tempdir()' in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to include `incl.data=TRUE` in the leaflet function. For example,

```
map<-leaflet(data=leafdat, dest=downloaddir, style=sty,
             title="index", base.map="osm",
             incl.data=TRUE,  popup=popup)
```

Check out [this](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/04/11/using-r-to-quickly-create-an-interactive-online-map-using-the-leafletr-package/) post that shows how to do this in detail.